# Implementing a Function using for-loops and matrix multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab

My goal is to implement a function which performs fourier synthesis in matlab, as part of learning the language. The function implements the following expression:

```
y = sum(ak*exp((i*2*pi*k*t)/T)
```

where k is the index, ak is a vector of fourier coefficients, t is a time vector of sampled times, and T is the period of the signal.

I have tried something like this:

```
for counter = -N:1:N
    k = y+N+1;
    y(k) = ak(k)*exp((i*2*pi*k*t)/T);
        % y is a vector of length 2N+1
end
```

However, this gives me an error that the sides do not have equal numbers of items within them. This makes sense to me, since t is a vector of arbitrary length, and thus I am trying to make y(k) equal to numerous things rather than one thing. Instead, I suspect I need to try something like:

```
for counter = -N:1:N
    k=y+N+1;
    for t = 0:1/fs:1
        %sum over t elements for exponential operation
    end
    %sum over k elements to generate y(k)
end
```

However, I'm supposedly able to implement this using purely matrix multiplication. How could I do this? I've tried to wrap my head around what Matlab is doing, but honestly, it's so far from the other languages I know that I don't really have any sense of what matlab's doing under the hood. Understanding how to change between operations on matrices and operations in for loops would be profoundly helpful.

Comment: You might be better of asking this at https://math.stackexchange.com or https://electronics.stackexchange.com since it requires understanding fourier synthesis.

Comment: Please consider writing a concise question or title. And provide a minimal working example. None of your code runs as `y` and `i` are never initialized. Further, are you aware that you don't use the loop-control variable `counter`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kron` to reach your goal without `for` loops, i.e., matrix representation:

```
y = a*exp(1j*2*pi*kron(k.',t)/T);
```

where `a`,`k` and `t` are all assumed as row-vectors

**Example**

```
N = 3;
k = -N:N;
t = 1:0.5:5;
T = 15;
a = 1:2*N+1;
y = a*exp(1j*2*pi*kron(k.',t)/T);
```

such that

```
y =

 Columns 1 through 6:

   19.1335 +  9.4924i   10.4721 + 10.6861i    2.0447 +  8.9911i   -4.0000 +  5.1962i   -6.4721 +  0.7265i   -5.4611 -  2.8856i

 Columns 7 through 9:

   -2.1893 -  4.5489i    1.5279 -  3.9757i    4.0000 -  1.7321i
```